# amplify datastore Error: Expected scalar and got User

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, datastore, aws-amplify

Working with amplify datastore and edited schema.graphql as following and when I enter "amplify codegen models" I get this error "**Error: Expected scalar and got User**" However the code was generated successfully. How would I be able to fix this error?

```
type User
  @model
  @key(name: "ByEmail", fields: ["email"], queryField: "userByEmail")
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  gender: String!
  birthdate: String!
  faceImage: String
  favoriteAvatar: [Avatar] @connection(fields: ["avatarId"])
  totalVideoTransform: Int
  registerAt: AWSDateTime!
}

type Avatar
  @model
  @key(name: "ByAvatrId", fields: ["avatarId"], queryField: "avatarByAvatarId")
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "favoriteUser", operations: [create, update, read] }]) {
  id: ID!
  avatarId: String!
  gender: String!
  favoriteUser: [User] @connection(fields: ["email"])
  totalVideoTransform: Int
}

type UserLoginLog
  @model
  @key(name: "ByUser", fields: ["user"], queryField: "userLoginLogByUser")
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create] }]) {
  id: ID!
  user: User @connection(fields: ["email"])
  loginAt: AWSDateTime!
}

type VideoTransformLog
  @model
  @key(name: "ByUser", fields: ["user"], queryField: "videoTransformLogByUser")
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create] }]) {
  id: ID!
  user: User @connection(fields: ["email"])
  avatar: Avatar @connection(fields: ["avatarId"])
  videoTransformAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your types "UserLoginLog" and "VideoTransformLog", remove "user" from the @key(... fields).
So don't place names that correspond to a type in fields[].